# can I pass a list of column addresses in the CellRangeAddressList of POI Library?

Tags: java, java-8, apache-poi

I am trying to generate an excel sheet with some data validation. The range is not continuous. In my case, I have to apply a validation to random columns(or alternative columns).

The code goes like this:

```
    DataValidation dataValidation2 = null;
    DataValidationConstraint constraint2 = null;
    DataValidationHelper validationHelper2 = null;

    validationHelper2 = new XSSFDataValidationHelper((XSSFSheet) sheet);
    CellRangeAddressList addressList2 = new CellRangeAddressList(1, rowIndex-1, 5, 5);
    constraint2 = validationHelper2.createExplicitListConstraint(convertListToString(countryValues));
    dataValidation2 = validationHelper2.createValidation(constraint2, addressList2);
    dataValidation2.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation2);


    DataValidation dataValidation3 = null;
    DataValidationConstraint constraint3 = null;
    DataValidationHelper validationHelper3 = null;

    validationHelper3 = new XSSFDataValidationHelper((XSSFSheet) sheet);
    CellRangeAddressList addressList3 = new CellRangeAddressList(1, rowIndex-1, 7, 7);
    constraint3 = validationHelper3.createExplicitListConstraint(convertListToString(countryValues));
    dataValidation3 = validationHelper3.createValidation(constraint3, addressList3);
    dataValidation3.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation3);

    DataValidation dataValidation4 = null;
    DataValidationConstraint constraint4 = null;
    DataValidationHelper validationHelper4 = null;

    validationHelper4 = new XSSFDataValidationHelper((XSSFSheet) sheet);
    CellRangeAddressList addressList4 = new CellRangeAddressList(1, rowIndex-1, 9, 9);
    constraint4 = validationHelper4.createExplicitListConstraint(convertListToString(countryValues));
    dataValidation4 = validationHelper4.createValidation(constraint4, addressList4);
    dataValidation4.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation4);

    DataValidation dataValidation5 = null;
    DataValidationConstraint constraint5 = null;
    DataValidationHelper validationHelper5 = null;

    validationHelper5 = new XSSFDataValidationHelper((XSSFSheet) sheet);
    CellRangeAddressList addressList5 = new CellRangeAddressList(1, rowIndex-1, 11, 11);
    constraint5 = validationHelper5.createExplicitListConstraint(convertListToString(countryValues));
    dataValidation5 = validationHelper5.createValidation(constraint5, addressList5);
    dataValidation5.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation5);

    DataValidation dataValidation6 = null;
    DataValidationConstraint constraint6 = null;
    DataValidationHelper validationHelper6 = null;

    validationHelper6 = new XSSFDataValidationHelper((XSSFSheet) sheet);
    CellRangeAddressList addressList6 = new CellRangeAddressList(1, rowIndex-1, 13, 13);
    constraint6 = validationHelper6.createExplicitListConstraint(convertListToString(countryValues));
    dataValidation6 = validationHelper6.createValidation(constraint6, addressList6);
    dataValidation6.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation6);
```

Ignore the redundancy object creations, I would like to pass pick a cell range with a list of a start-end row and start-end column values for the CellRangeAddressList constructor. Or is there any simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @Holger I was checking if CellRangeAddressList can accept a list of column range.

Comment: A short look into [the documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddressList.html) reveals that you can’t pass them to the constructor, but there’s an `addCellRangeAddress` method…